# Is a Flow formula comparing strings for capitalization changes possible?

Tags: visual-workflow, string

I have a flow automation that is triggered based on text changes in a few different fields. In cases of an update, we have some scenarios where users will change values in capitalization alone, from "smith" to "Smith". I had (incorrectly) thought that using "Is Changed" would recognize this type of change, but apparently that is not the case for Salesforce formulas (at least so far). And I've not found any docs yet that indicate formulas are only valid in situations outside of capitalization comparisons.

Apparently the only way I've come across so far is to use Apex for a string comparison that includes case using the `equals()` method. Which, if the only option, and I still want to use my flow, I'm thinking I need to create an Invokable aware method that I can pass in two string and get some sort of comparison output that I can integrate into the flow itself. But before doing that I figured it'd be worth asking here if my thinking is in line with what's possible today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct in your reasoning. String comparisons are almost universally case-insensitive, except in some very specific cases (like Id/Lookup fields). An invocable method would be the only way to get a case-sensitive comparison. Fortunately, that's fairly trivial:

```
public class CompareStrings {
  public class Input {
    @InvocableVariable public String string1;
    @InvocableVariable public String string2;
  }
  public class Output {
    Output(Boolean isEqual) {
      areEqual = isEqual;
    }
    @InvocableVariable public Boolean areEqual;
  }
  @InvocableMethod(description='Case-sensitive Compare' label='Case-Sensitive Compare') 
  public Output[] compareTwo(Input[] values) {
    Output[] outputs = new Output[0];
    for(Input value: values) {
      outputs.add(
        new Output(
          value.string1 == null && value.string2 == null ||
          value.string1 != null && value.string1.equals(value.string2)
        ));
    }
    return outputs;
  }
}
```

We first see if both are null, and if so, return true, otherwise we check if the first string is not null (if so, we return false), and equals the other string.

Comment: Sweet! I went ahead and wrote up the method for it, but wanted to get confirmation. It's basically the same as what you have here. Thanks for taking the time to write it out!

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post, but figured I'd share in case it helps others. You have a couple options with formula fields and flow:

Use a Boolean formula field to say record field 1 != record field 2, which can then be applied to decision nodes. Example: {!$Record.PersonMailingCity} != {!$Record.PersonOtherCity}

I believe the FIND() function is case sensitive. So you could say find field 1 in field 2 conceivably. I think the first option is a little easier to follow though.